# ATMEGA168A - F_CPU warning

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I have written the code below in order to make an ATMEGA168A blink a small led:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 1000000UL

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0b00000010;
    PORTB = 0b00000000;

    while(1)
    {
        PORTB ^= 1 << 1;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

The compiler is giving me a warning as follows:

```
Warning     #warning "F_CPU not defined for <util/delay.h>"
```

Here is where this warning comes from (delay.h)

```
#ifndef F_CPU
/* prevent compiler error by supplying a default */
# warning "F_CPU not defined for <util/delay.h>"
# define F_CPU 1000000UL
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is my declaration incorrect?

Comment: **never** use `while(1)` anywhere except for private experimentation, that code **will** deadlock at some point. Its OK if you only do hobby-projects but dont get accustomed to it!

Comment: An AVR always use round robin as far as I know...

Comment: @specializt No it will not. The code is fine.

Comment: @nos Yes it will. Every unbounded loop will create deadlocks BY DESIGN - sometimes during interrupts on x86 systems, sometimes during unexpected IO states and whatnot. Unbounded loops are the main cause for bluescreens, deadlocks and software crashes, this is true even for microcontrollers albeit not being as ubiquitous; for many reasons.

Comment: @specializt No. Looping forever is fine in many contexts. Not all, not everywhere, you can create deadlocks, but that's not because of a while(1), and there is no potential for deadlock in in this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define `F_CPU` before that inclusion.  You could do it on the command line when compiling, or put it in your source.  You defining this symbol is you letting the build system know how fast your particular CPU is running.  (I.e., you don't get to change the actual speed this way).

For a discussion, see http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/understanding-fcpu

Comment: I did it before the inclusion and still get the warning!

Answer (score 2):

The scope of a macro definition is from its `#define` directive to the end of the source file or a corresponding `#undef`.

The value of `F_CPU` is tested in the `util/delay.h` header. But when that test happens, your `#define F_CPU` has not yet been  processed.

You can either move it before `#include <util/delay>` or define that macro using a compiler option. The latter would be my choice. Then you have to change only one item in the build (Makefile, project settings, ...).